# I want to split an array into multiple arrays using php

Tags: php, arrays

here is my o/p,i want to get multiple arrays,if array contains one more strings with spaces are there in . how will i take that also

```
Array ( [0] => KERALA-682030 );
Array ( [0] => INDIA );
Array ( [0] => Date : 19 Aug 2015 ) etc.........18 arrays are there
```

I want:

```
$arr[1]=KERALA;
$arr[2]=682030
$arr[3]=INDIA
$arr[4]=Date
$arr[5]=19 Aug 2015;
```

remaining Arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => Address :    IX/355 G2, 2ND FLR, MLMLALL MANSION IJKIKK ROAD, KUXHSIDFSFF  KUGGGGGG PO, KJJSJFSJF ErJSDFJSF ) Array ( [0] => KOCHI ) Array ( [0] => KERALA-6812555 ) Array ( [0] => INDIA ) Array ( [0] => Date : 19 Aug 2015 ) Array ( [0] => Account Number :  _000000555444545889 ) Array ( [0] => Account Description:   CURRENT A/C - COLLECTION A/C ) Array ( [0] => Branch : Skkgdgdg ) Array ( [0] => Drawing Power :    0.00 ) Array ( [0] => Interest Rate(% p.a.):    0.0 ) Array ( [0] => MOD Balance :  0.00 ) Array ( [0] => CIF No. : _44454444545 ) Array ( [0] => IFS Code :    HY155555555 ) Array ( [0] => MICR Code :    _XXXXXXX) Array ( [0] => Balance on 1 Aug 2010 : 1,12,494.98 ) Array ( [0] => Start Date :  1 Aug 2015 ) Array ( [0] => End Date :  19 Aug 2015 ) Array ( [0] => Txn Date   Value Date  Description Ref No./Cheque No.  Branch Code Debit   Credit  Balance ) Array ( [0] => 12 Aug 2015    12 Aug 2015 TO TRANSFER-INB TAX RETERN JULY--   CT1254555 TRANSFER TO 12212121211 Mr.XXXXXT G / 99922   12,300.00   1,00,194.98 ) Array ( [0] => 17 Aug 2015    17 Aug 2015 BY TRANSFER-NEFT*HDS5008888885*KEhhhh CARS PVT--    TRANSFER FROM 319255555554 / 4430   13,000.00   1,13,194.98 ) Array ( [0] => 18 Aug 2015    18 Aug 2015 TO TRANSFER-INB BSNL_RECHARGE Payments--    dfsff122121212 TRANSFER TO 3199597162098 / 99922    135.00  1,13,059.98 ) Array ( [0] => )
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your you get that data? Can you show me?

Comment: i added  remaining arrays the code above.i want to get multiple arrays,i just want to insert the data into my database.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function to explode or separate out individual elements in the an array. This can be useful if you want to take an array and break it into parts. This code that I'm including might not do what you want it to do, but I think what you're looking for is explode().

```
$addressArray[1] = '1234 Wilker Way';
$addressArray[2] = '5678 Jonas Town';
function breakArrayUp($passedArray1,$passedArray2)
{
global $addressArray;


foreeach($break as $passedArray)
{
$x++;
$final[] = explode($passwedArray[$x]));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `array_chunk` function http://php.net/array_chunk

---

Alternatively here's a very good function: (but this is slower then the PHP function above)

```
/**
 * Split a array into semi-equal sized chunks.
 * A so-called 'columnizer'
 *
 * @param array $array          The array to split
 * @param array $numberOfChunks The number of chunks
 * @param bool  $vertical       Whether to order vertically or horizonally
 *
 * @return array Array with $numberOfColumns nodes with items of $array
 */
function arraySplit($array, $numberOfChunks = 2, $vertical = true)
{
    if ($vertical) {
        $perColumn = floor(count($array) / $numberOfChunks);
        $rest = count($array) % $numberOfChunks;
        $perColumns = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfChunks; $i++) {
            $perColumns[$i] = $perColumn + ($i < $rest ? 1 : 0);
        }
        foreach ($perColumns as $rows) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
                $data[$i][] = array_shift($array);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($array as $node) {
            $data[$i][] = $node;
            $i = ($i >= ($numberOfChunks - 1) ? 0 : $i + 1);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll asume you want to split the strings by this three delimiters:  `'-'`,`' : '` or `' '`
In that case:

```
//array with all the split elements from all arrays 
$total_array = array();

//do the following foreach of your arrays

$array_to_split = array('KERALA-682030');

//replace the '-' and ' : ' by a space ' '
$string_to_split = $array_to_split[0];
$string_to_split = str_replace('-',' ',$string_to_split);
$string_to_split = str_replace(' : ',' ',$string_to_split);
$splited_array = explode(' ',$string_to_split);

$total_array = array_merge($total_array, $splited_array);
```